# Persistent title with marker in Google Maps Api v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This should be easy but I can't find anything to help.

I'm setting a custom marker for Google Maps Api like so:

```
    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Fisk");
    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.doghouse));
    mMap.addMarker(marker);
```

I'm wanting to be able to make the title persistent, so that it is always showing. I'm also wondering how to edit the appearance of the title! The title will eventually be dynamic, or I would have made the image include the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should note some GoogleMaps specifics:

- Can't display multiple marker `InfoWindow`s
- Marker specific click listeners aren't available, though you could check which marker was clicked
- Click on a marker, hides the `InfoWindow` even if you consume the click in the listener
- Click on the map, closes the opened `InfoWindow`

To overcome those here's a piece of code:

```
final Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
        new LatLng(51.5072, 0.1275)).title("B"));
marker.showInfoWindow();

mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker m) {
        marker.showInfoWindow();
        return true; // Consume the clicks
    }
});

mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
        marker.showInfoWindow();
    }
});
```

Note: This will work with a single Marker, if you want multiple Marker titles visible at the same time, you're better off adding an overlay.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the input! I am getting the error "cannot find symbol class Marker," I'm obviously new to this is there an easy way to figure out what classes I need to import to be able to access this?

Comment: @user1610719 You have a few options. First: [google](http://bit.ly/11r36Td), second: use an IDE (Eclipse, AS, etc.), which allows easy imports with a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Man that would have been so easy if I knew it was called an InfoWindow! Thanks got it now. For others, this is a great resource https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows

Answer (score 1):

You can make your your own marker layout and add this

```
LinearLayout tv = (LinearLayout) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.test_layout, null, false);
        tv.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        tv.layout(0, 0, tv.getMeasuredWidth(), tv.getMeasuredHeight()); 

        tv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        tv.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bm = tv.getDrawingCache();


and      BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bm);
                BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitudemy, longitudemy)).title("xxxx").snippet("xxxxx").icon(icon));
```